# how do i install Aerospike REST Gateway?

Tags: rest, installation, aerospike

i want to use REST from aerospike because its said language agnostic, im using Ubuntu 20.  im trying to understand intallation part here :
https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-rest-gateway
https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-rest-gateway/blob/master/docs/installation-and-config.md

but its soo unclear what to do first and they jumps to "./gradlew build" at start. i put mindlessly to terminal its show like this, totally no clue

```
# ./gradlew build
bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few ways to run the REST Gateway.

1. You can clone the repo's master branch and build it yourself. You can then run the jar file as shown in the readme.

```
make build
java -jar build/libs/aerospike-rest-gateway-<VERSION>.jar --aerospike.restclient.hostname=<aerospike-host>
```

2. Download the already built jar from the download [page](https://aerospike.com/download/) or download it using

```
wget https://download.aerospike.com/artifacts/aerospike-client-rest/<VERSION>/aerospike-client-rest-<VERSION>.tgz
```

- Untar the archive

```
tar -xzf aerospike-client-rest-<VERSION>.tgz
```

- Run the jar

```
java -jar aerospike-client-rest-2.0.1/as-rest-client-<VERSION>.jar --aerospike.restclient.hostname=<aerospike-host>
```

3. Use docker:

```
docker run -itd --rm -p 8080:8080 --name AS_Rest1 -e aerospike_restclient_hostname=<aerospike-host> aeropsike/aerospike-rest-gateway:latest
```

Note 1: These examples assume security is disabled.
Note 2: The REST client was recently renamed the REST Gateway, which is the reason for the differing artifact names.

As far as why `./gradlew build` is not running, it is a bit hard to tell. Running `./gradlew build` assumes you cloned the repo and the repo is your current working directory.  If you provide more info about your CWD and the steps you have followed up to this point I can help further.